# Which question list should I look to find my unanswered question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, question-lists

I have asked a question that has just 10 views. I want to be sure that others will see the question in one list at least!

But I cannot find any list having my question in the middle. Has the question gone to 2nd and 3rd page? or what?

The question is on Stack Overflow.

Comment: There are *lots* of questions asked on Stack Overflow. If you asked the question more than a few minutes ago, it is very likely to be on the second or third page. But that's okay, because people use lots of strategies to find questions to answer. For example, sorting by tags or looking at only unanswered questions.

Comment: @CodyGray That would have made a lovely answer...

Comment: Just make sure it has good, appropriate tags and it should be found by the right people. If that still doesn't work, see the possible duplicate already mentioned

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. I have already done my best to tag it well. Anyway maybe I should still wait for viewers (and hopefully someone to answer)

Comment: It's not really a duplicate. Or at least, it doesn't sound like to me that the question is *old* yet.